# How to make usernames as vocabulary in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, vocabulary

I am making a website using Drupal 7, in which a user may assign tasks to another user while editing a content node. I was thinking of doing this by making the Username list appear as a tag list with autocomplete. But I am unable to find any modules or methods to do it the Drupal way. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what exactly would you like to achieve, anyway, there is a module which allows to add a user/node reference fields:

> http://drupal.org/project/references

I hope I helped a bit. If not, please, try to add more details, thanks.